# Python Pandas: Find Match and Assign Higher Value

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

Given the following data frame:

```
import pandas as pd
DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'A', 'B', 'B'], 
                   'COL2': [1, 1 ,2 ,2],
                   'COL3': [2, 3, 4, 6]})

>>> DF

  COL1  COL2  COL3
0   A    1     2
1   A    1     3
2   B    2        4
3   B    2        6
```

I want pandas to find all occurrences of COL1 == 'A' and COL2 == 1 and, when it does, use the higher number found in column 3 for all rows such that COL3 is always 3 for A and 1.

However, I only want this to occur if the difference in values is only 1.

Therefore, the rows for B and 2 will remain the same for COL3 values.

The desired result looks like this:

```
  COL1  COL2  COL3
0   A    1     3
1   A    1     3
2   B    2     4
3   B    2     6
```

Note: It will not be sorted in any particular way to begin with, as this data frame was.

Comment: I think there is a typo in your question, you have mentioned COL3 val as 5 , but you have pasted 6 in the dataframe on row 3

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
In [71]:
DF.groupby([DF.COL1 , DF.COL2])['COL3'].transform(lambda x : x.max() if np.abs(x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0])  == 1 else x)
Out[71]:
0    3
1    3
2    4
3    6
Name: COL3, dtype: int64
```

Comment: Thanks,  Nader. How would I do the comparison of values in COL3 if there were 3 or more rows in the group? What if the dataframe were large and unsorted? And how do I return a data frame?

Comment: actually you have to define what you need to do if you have more than 2 rows , here you're subtracting the second value from the first , so if you have more what do you want to do ? also if the data frame is not sorted we overcome this problem by taking the absolute value as you've seen in the solution

Comment: For n rows in a group, I want to subtract the smallest value from the largest for COL3. If the absolute value of the result is 1 then assign the largest value to all n rows of COL3 for the group. Else, do nothing.

Comment: I tried switching x.iloc[1] and x.iloc[0] with np.max (DF.COL3) and np.min(DF.COL3) but it didn't work.

Comment: actually you've already solved it on your own :) , you can do this `x.max() - x.min()` instead of `x.iloc[1] - x.iloc[0]` , there is no need to take the absolute value as you're ready subtracting the small value from the bigger one

Comment: Great! One more newb question: how do I get it to return as a dataframe?

Comment: you don't need to , instead you can assign the output values to the existing data frame by doing `DF['new_column_name'] = your group by statement`

Comment: I wish you were here to receive a mid-air high-five. Thanks!

Comment: you're welcome :) , glad I could help , wish you always the best

Answer (score 1):

Since you have just mentioned a specific condition, the answer is accordingly framed to align with your requirements.

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np

DF = pd.DataFrame({'COL1': ['A', 'A','B','B'], 'COL2' : [1,1,2,2],
                   'COL3' : [2,3,4,6]})

# store max value of COL3 in a variable for condition COL1=A and COL2=1,
max_val = max((DF[(DF.COL1=='A') & (DF.COL2==1)])['COL3'].values)
print max_val

#create function to check for values
def change_col(column1,column2,column3):
    if column1=='A' and column2 == 1:
        out = max_val
    else:
        out = column3
    return out

#apply function looking at values in all 3 columns
DF['COL3'] = np.vectorize(change_col)(DF['COL1'],DF['COL2'],DF['COL3']) 
print DF
```

Result:

```
 COL1  COL2  COL3
0    A     1     3
1    A     1     3
2    B     2     4
3    B     2     6
```